# Object wrappers and forms

Tags: oop, design-patterns, symfony, symfony-forms

I am developing an ecommerce platform and came across a difficulty. Basically, I have in my scenario a Product, Option and OptionValue. A product might have multiple options which might have multiple values. The problem is how to store it in a way that is easy to create and edit.

[image]

The problem is I've a direct reference to the OptionValue, which is mutable. I need to keep immutable information about the Option and OptionValue (for example, if a order was made and the color was green, even if this option is changed to lime green, the order must keep showing as green). In that case, I need to save some properties of Option (the option name - "Colors" for example) and of each OptionValue (the value of each option - "red" for example). The way I thought, it would require a structure very similar to the existing structure: a new class ItemOption referencing Option and a ItemOptionValue referencing OptionValue.

[image]

So, this was my attempt:

To create a form to display my options I have:

```
class OptionSelectorType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        foreach ($options['product']->getOptions() as $option) {
            $builder->add($option->getId(), 'choice', array('choice_list' => new ObjectChoiceList($option->getValues());));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a DataTransformer to convert a collection of OptionValue in a collection of OrderItemOption:

```
class OrderItemOptionToOptionValueTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{ 
    public function transform($lineOptions)
    {
      if(!$lineOptions) {
        return array();
      }
      $values = array();
      foreach($lineOptions as $lineOption) {
        $lineOption->getOption()->getId();
        $values[$id] = array();

        foreach($lineOption->getValues() as $lineOptionValue) {
          $values[$id][] = $lineOptionValue->getOptionValue();
        }
      }

        return $values;
    }

    public function reverseTransform($values)
    {
      $collection = new ArrayCollection();
      foreach($values as $optionId => $optionValues) {
        if(!$optionValues) {
          continue;
        }

        $lineOption = new OrderItemOption();
        $optionValues = is_array($optionValues) ? $optionValues : array($optionValues);
        foreach($optionValues as $optionValue) {
          $lineOptionValue = new OrderItemOptionValue();
          $lineOptionValue->setOptionValue($optionValue);
          $lineOption->addValue($lineOptionValue);
        }

        $lineOption->setOption($optionValue->getOption());
        $collection->add($lineOption);
      }

      return $collection;
    }
}
```

Finally, my OrderItemType form:

```
class OrderItemType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
      $builder->add(
        $builder->create('options', 'option_selector', array('options' => $options['options']))
        ->addModelTransformer(new OrderItemOptionToOptionValueTransformer())
      );
    }
}
```

It works but doesn't seem to me a good approach, once the OptionValue will be always recreated, never updated.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I will keep it simple. You can stick with your structure but instead of transforming things on the fly, keep them at the same state.

**What do I mean?**

Whenever an Option is created, create the corresponding ItemOption. The same goes with the OptionValue and ItemOptionValue. The relation between the two is a one-to-one connection, whereas the Option and OptionValue don't know the connected ItemOption and ItemOptionValue.

Now if a change occurs to the OptionValue, you can query for the connected ItemOptionValue and change the things you need to change (depends on internal structure).

**How to store the connection?**

Use whatever persistence method you already use. For the case of a database, store the connection in one table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE item_option_to_option (
    optionID INT(10) NOT NULL,
    itemOptionID INT(10) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY (optionID, itemOptionID)
);
```

If possible I would use Foreign Keys to link the both columns to the corresponding columns in the tables `item_option` and `option`. It works the same with OptionValue and ItemOptionValue.

**How to handle the change?**

Whenever the controller for the OptionValue change is called, simply update the Item* models as well.

If an Option or OptionValue is deleted, it is up to you, if you delete the ItemOption or ItemOptionValue as well.